# KeyError when key is in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

So I stumbled upon this weird bug.  I made a dictionary that contains these keys:

```
database_5x5 = {'(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)': [(0, 0), (0, 1)],
                '(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)': [(0, 0), (0, 3)],
                '(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)': [(0, 1)],
                '(0, 0, 1, 1, 1)': [(0, 3)],
                '(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)': [(0, 4)],
                '(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)': [(0, 0)],
                '(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)': [(0, 2)]
                }
```

This is the code that accesses the dictionary:

```
 bottom = tuple(puzzle[len(puzzle)-1])
    next_moves = database_5x5[bottom]
```

My code runs and gives me this error:

```
KeyError: (0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

I'm not sure what could be wrong here...
I appreciate the help!

Comment: The keys are strings, but it looks like you're trying to use tuples.

Comment: Try `database_5x5[str(bottom)]`

Comment: Either change the dict to have tuples as keys, or convert your tuples to strings when doing the lookup (e.g. `database_5x5[str(bottom)]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in the dictionary are of type `string`. You should cast `bottom`:

```
next_moves = database_5x5[str(bottom)]
```

Comment: Ah so this is what happens when I'm sleep deprived... I miss these basic things... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every key in your dictionary `database_5x5` is a string, but you request an element with a **tuple** key `bottom`. Try to convert a key type, for example, this way:

```
next_moves = database_5x5[str(bottom)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys of your dict are of the type string. So you need to make sure of two things.

1) This segment `tuple(puzzle[len(puzzle)-1])` produces a string.
2) (silly one) The spaces and commas are exactly match.

Fix:
1) Change your keys to be not strings.
2) Cast `bottom` to a string - `database_5x5[str(bottom)]`